# PowerShell pipeline stucks

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I have .NET core console app and try to execute PS commands from it. Following code correctly works on windows machine, but stucks on Linux (Ubuntu) machine.

```
var pipeLine = _runspace.CreatePipeline();

var myCommand = new Command(script, true);            
pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);            
pipeLine.Input.Close();

Console.WriteLine("Running pipeline...");
pipeLine.InvokeAsync();

while (pipeLine.PipelineStateInfo.State != PipelineState.Completed)
{
     Thread.Sleep(100);
     Console.WriteLine(pipeLine.PipelineStateInfo.State.ToString());//Status is still 'Running' infinitely on linux machine
}
System.Console.WriteLine("PipeLine finished");
while (!pipeLine.Output.EndOfPipeline)
    commandResults.Add(pipeLine.Output.Read());
```

Both machines have the same version of .NET core.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7885